# how to call .asmx c# webservice in php

Tags: php, soap

i was call .asmx web service in php using soap but it's not working.

https://atgbureau.uat.sc-oasys.com/ws/integration/savillehrxml/Assessment.asmx?WSDL

this is web service url.

any idea how to use c# .asmx web service in php.

i am try to call using soap client but it's always show below error

C91EFAE5-1E5F-43B8-8613-A763C5B8F770Saville Consulting00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000ErrorbusinessURL for subject to access assessment.ErrorInternal Error2016-08-11

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will show you the methods that are available on this web service:

```
$wsdl = "https://atgbureau.uat.sc-oasys.com/ws/integration/savillehrxml/Assessment.asmx?WSDL";
$soapclient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('exceptions' => true, 'soap_version'  => SOAP_1_1));
var_dump($soapclient->__getFunctions());
```

And here is the code to get the data types you will need to interact with the methods:

```
$wsdl = "https://atgbureau.uat.sc-oasys.com/ws/integration/savillehrxml/Assessment.asmx?WSDL";
$soapclient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('exceptions' => true, 'soap_version'  => SOAP_1_1));
var_dump($soapclient->__getTypes());
```